# Center text with background extending from text on the left to content-box on the right

Tags: html, css

I was asked to code an unusual shape background on some centered text.

The text should be centered and have it's background extend to the right edge of the content-box.

[image: Background extends right]

How can I do this with CSS?

Comment: @ImagineStudios Please include an image description in future edits.

Comment: @OP don't forget to pick an answer if one works for you.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/7U688/

The text centering is cake. 
The tricky bit is extending the background off into one direction.
This is one way of accomplishing this:

```
#outer{
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#inner{
    margin:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
p{
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;  // or an image
    margin:0 -999em 0 5px;
    padding: 5px 999em 5px 5px;
    line-height:1;
}
```

In this case - I use a huge padding and an equally huge negative margin to keep an element in flow, but visually extend outside of its borders. A benefit of this technique is that it allows the dev to keep an element in normal static or relative position.

Finally, use `overflow:hidden` in a parent element to prevent unwanted bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:after`, you may do something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfc72/2/).

This allows the text to be centered normally without using margin and padding hacks.

```
p {
    display: table;
    background: black;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p:after {
    content: '';
    background: black;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: On Chrome, at least for me, the bit extending off to the right hangs one pixel below the bottom line of text.

Comment: This requires a concrete height, not useful in production.

Comment: :after is css2 compliant, also.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pJ8D/)

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="text">You text</span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrapper {
   width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.text {
    background: yellow;

}
```

Comment: No, the key is the extending background. What does table-cell do anyway?

Comment: This isn't what he wants. :(

Comment: @bjb568: `table-cell` make the `vertical-align: middle` work :)

Comment: @Stiger Ah. I usually just match line-height with the height of the parent.

Comment: @bjb568 If the text is long(more than 1 line), maybe it can break layout (space between line is too height).